# Is it possible to set triggers for another spreadsheet in GAS?

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script, spreadsheet

I think it is possible to set a trigger with the GAS code below, but is it possible to set a trigger for another spreadsheet file?

```
ScriptApp.newTrigger(function_name).timeBased().everyDays(...).atHour(...).create();
```

Comment: It is possible to set up a trigger for another spreadsheet. However, you cannot set it up as a time-based trigger. You can check this [doc](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/script/spreadsheet-trigger-builder) for the available methods for spreadsheet triggers. Note that the trigger will be installed on the GAS project that ran the script, not on the GAS project that's bound to the spreadsheet in question. You can also consider submitting a feature request via Google's [Issue Tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/)

Comment: So the short answer is no.